# Numbers such that $a|n\implies a+1|n+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, divisibility

> Call a number $n\in\mathbb{N}$ "good" if $d+1|n+1,$ where $d$ is any divisor of $n.$ Find all good numbers.

One immediate thing we see is that $1$ is a good number because the only divisor of $1$ is $1$ and $1+1|1+1$ trivially. We see that $2$ isn't good as $1+1$ doesn't divide $2+1.$ However, any other prime works. The only divisors of a prime $p$ are $1$ and $p.$ Clearly, if $p≠2,$ then $2|p+1.$ Also, $p+1|p+1.$ So, all odd primes and the number $1$ are good.

I think there are no other good numbers. Clearly, any good number must be odd. Else, we would have that $2$ divides an odd number. Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be an odd composite number that is good. Take the largest divisor of $n$ that isn't $n$ itself and call it $k.$ Such a $k$ exists precisely because $n$ is composite. From how we've defined $k,$ we have $\sqrt{n}≤k<n.$ Now, $n=km$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}.$ Now, from $k+1|km+1,$ we get $km+1=t(k+1)$ for some $t\in\mathbb{N}.$ Reduce modulo $k$ to get $t\equiv_k1.$ Hence, $t=kb+1$ for some whole number $b.$ Sub this in to get $km+1=(kb+1)(k+1)=k^2b+kb+k+1.$ Suppose $b≠0.$ Then, $k^2b+kb+k+1≥nb+\sqrt{n}b+\sqrt{n}+1≥n+2\sqrt{n}+1>n+1.$ This gives $n+1>n+1,$ a contradiction. Hence, $b=0.$ This gives $t=1,$ and hence $m=1.$ This gives $n=k,$ contrary to our definition of $k.$ Hence, composite numbers aren't good.

This means that $1$ along with all odd primes are the only good numbers.

Does this look good (pun intended)? Any other ways to go about this?

Comment: This is how I would have solved it. The only thing you could do is to streamline the argument: Let $a \geq \sqrt{n}$ with $ak = n$. Note that $k \leq a$. If $n$ is good, then $a+1 | ak+1$. But $a+1 | ak+k$ anyways and hence must divide their difference, i.e. $a+1|k-1$. But the only way a bigger number can divide a smaller number is if $k-1 = 0$ or $k = 1$. Therefore $n$ must be prime. Then one shows that exactly the odd prime $n$ indeed work, as you already did.

Comment: Seems correct :)

Comment: @LionCoder, that's a nice argument.

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24d%2B1%5Cmid%20n%2B1%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Agood%2C%20OR%20content%3Adivisor&p=1), there's the AoPS threads [Lecture: "Diverse problems"](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2410137p19769642) (with your problem being its problem #$3$) and [Number theory](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1962973p13583170) (which says the source is "Romanian "Stars of Mathematics" Junior $2019$ P$1$").

Comment: The statement "Take the largest divisor of $n$ that isn't $n$ itself and call it $k$. Such a $k$ exists precisely because $n$ is composite." is imprecise. Such $k$ always exists, what is important is that $k>1$ when $n$ is composite.

Comment: I was about to post an answer , that used the same argument of @LionCoder, He should have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate Proof:

Let us assume a composite number $n = pk$ where $p$ is smallest prime and $k > 1$.

then

$$k+1|pk+1$$

$$k \equiv -1 \pmod{k+1}$$
We get  $p \equiv 1 \pmod{k+1}$

$$k \geq p$$

So, $p-1 = 0$ but $p = 1$ is not a prime.

Therefore, $k \leq 1$.

$k = 1$ gives prime

$k = 0$ is removed as it does not satisfy.